# Evaluation of condition failed. Rule item ID: Unknown, condition item ID: Unknown - Operation not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: sitecore, conditional-statements, analytics, rule, invalidoperationexception

I'm reviewing the Sitecore logs in my site and I'm getting a huge number of the following error:

> ERROR Evaluation of condition failed. Rule item ID: Unknown, condition item ID: Unknown
>
> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Message: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>
> Source: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Rules.AggregationAdaptor.HistoricalVisitContextBase.GetPages()
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.Conditions.HasVisitedPageCondition`1.Execute(T ruleContext)
>      at Sitecore.Rules.Conditions.WhenCondition`1.Evaluate(T ruleContext.......

In the past week, this error has occurred >10,500 times

I don't know what to do to figure out what is causing the error or to resolve it. I don't know if it's affecting site performance or not, but I'd like to resolve this issue so I don't have >10k errors happening each week.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solve the issue: https://sitecoreart.martinrayenglish.com/2017/10/sitecore-xdb-mechanics-guide-to.html

The most common cause of the error is due to old tests that are still part of the content item's configuration, that are either not stopped correctly, inactive or have been removed.

**Fixing the Issue**
The fix is to remove the bad/old test references from the item in question's Final Renderings XML field.

-Determine what item is throwing the testing exception.
-Enable raw values and standard fields in the “View” section of the “View” tab.
-Copy the Final Renderings XML value of the item and format it so that it is easy to read. This site does a nice job: https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html
-Paste you’re the XML into Visual Studio or another editor.
-Locate the attributes in the XML that have a s:pt and remove the attributes.
-Copy and paste the updated XML back into the item's Final Renderings field.
-Save and publish.

After this, the errors will stop appearing in your logs. You will however need to launch your test again.